# How to calculate distance between different IDs over time by group?

Tags: r, dplyr, distance

My (example) data is structured as follows... where the X and Y coordinates of participants, recorded under varying conditions, are collected over time:

```
    Individ <- data.frame(Participant = c("Bill", "Bill", "Bill", "Bill", "Bill", "Harry", "Harry", "Harry", "Harry","Harry", "Paul", "Paul", "Paul", "Paul", "Paul"),
                          Time = c(0.01, 0.02, 0.03, 0.04, 0.05, 0.01, 0.02, 0.03, 0.04, 0.05, 0.01, 0.02, 0.03, 0.04, 0.05),
                          Condition = c("Expr", "Expr", "Expr", "Expr", "Expr", "Con", "Con", "Con", "Con", "Con", "Nor", "Nor", "Nor", "Nor", "Nor"),
                          X = c(26.07, 26.06, 26.05, 26.09, 26.04, 26.65, 26.64, 26.62, 26.63, 26.62, 27.99, 28.01, 28.01, 28.02, 28.02),
                          Y = c(-5.01, -5.12, -5.14, -5.18, -5.2065, -12.37, 12.36, -12.35, -12.34, 12.33, -5.52, -5.514, -5.51, -5.50, -5.4962))
```

The X and Y coordinates are captured from the same location. I can calculate the distance covered by each Participant using the following:

```
require(plyr)
require(dplyr)
DistanceOutput <- Individ %>%
     arrange(Participant, Time, Condition) %>%
     group_by(Participant, Condition) %>%
     mutate( lagX = lag(X, order_by=Time), lagY = lag(Y, order_by=Time)) %>%
     rowwise() %>%
     mutate(Distance = dist( matrix( c(X,Y,lagX,lagY),nrow=2,byrow=TRUE) )) %>%
     select(-lagX, -lagY)
```

However, how can I calculate the distance between each `Participant` over `Time`, according to their `Condition`. For example, the distance between Bill and Harry, Bill and Paul plus Harry and Paul over Time?

My dataset is 179,800 obs. so ideally, a quick solution is preferred. Thank you!

Comment: `Error: object 'Location' not found` when trying to run your code. Also, not sure what you're wanting for output. Why are we picking on Bill and Harry?

Comment: Good points, thank you. I have edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way to calculate the distance between each participant at each time point. I doubt it's the most efficient way, but maybe someone else will come along with a more elegant solution.

You said that you'd like to calculate the distance between participants for each `Condition`. In your sample data, there's only one participant in each condition. However, the solution below can easily be extended to be applied by `Condition` in addition to `Time`.

```
library(reshape2)
library(dplyr)

# Calculate distance matrix for each Time
res = lapply(unique(Individ$Time), function(i) {

  mat = as.matrix(Individ[Individ$Time==i, c("X","Y")])
  rownames(mat) = Individ$Participant[Individ$Time==i]

  # Distance matrix
  d = as.matrix(dist(mat))

  # Keep only lower triangle
  d[upper.tri(d, diag=TRUE)] = NA

  # Return data frame with distances, time and participants
  data.frame(Time=i, d) %>% add_rownames("P1")
})

# Combine all time points into single long data frame of distances
res = bind_rows(res) %>% 
  melt(id.var=c("Time","P1"), variable.name="P2", value.name="Distance") %>%
  filter(!is.na(Distance)) %>% 
  rowwise %>%
  mutate(Pair = paste(sort(c(as.character(P1), as.character(P2))), collapse="-")) %>% 
  select(Pair, Time, Distance) %>%
  arrange(Pair, Time)

res
```

> ```
>          Pair  Time  Distance
> 1  Bill-Harry  0.01  7.382818
> 2  Bill-Harry  0.02 17.489620
> 3  Bill-Harry  0.03  7.232496
> 4  Bill-Harry  0.04  7.180334
> 5  Bill-Harry  0.05 17.546089
> 6   Bill-Paul  0.01  1.986580
> 7   Bill-Paul  0.02  1.989406
> 8   Bill-Paul  0.03  1.994618
> 9   Bill-Paul  0.04  1.956349
> 10  Bill-Paul  0.05  2.001081
> 11 Harry-Paul  0.01  6.979835
> 12 Harry-Paul  0.02 17.926427
> 13 Harry-Paul  0.03  6.979807
> 14 Harry-Paul  0.04  6.979807
> 15 Harry-Paul  0.05 17.881091
> ```